# Is there an event emitted for socket.io ack/responses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, feathersjs, engine.io

I'm using socket.io and express both with feathersjs.  For metrics gathering I'm trying to capture round-trips for requests made both through Express as well as through socket.io.

The express side is easy with express middleware.

I can catch the socket.io *inbound* request via `socket.use`:

```
const app = express(feathers());
... (set up feathers services etc.)

app.configure(socketio(function(io) {
  io.use(function(socket, next) {
    socket.use((packet, next) => {
      ... (extract the verb and pathing info from the packet)
      next();
    });
    next();
  });
});
```

However, I can't find any equivalent of `socket.use` on the outbound/acknowledgement side.  There's some events inside engine.io under the covers but I can't access them.

I'm really trying to find an equivalent set of events emitted for each request/response (the latter being the equivalent to `finish` in express).

I can't use connect/disconnect events here; I want to capture each request made over the socket *and the responses sent for them*, regardless of the feathers service and module.

Feathers.js hooks could be used for this, but it would require passing a bunch of context from the socket.io middleware into feathers, which I was hoping to not do.

Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes here looking for a way to do this, I'm not sure why I didn't think of it sooner.

The inbound packet (available in `socket.use`) will include a function as its *last* parameter if it should be acknowledged.

Wrapping the last function to inject my own logic worked.

pseudo-code

```
socket.use((packet, next) => {
  const id = uuidv4();

  console.log(`start of request: ${id}`);

  const cb = packet[packet.length - 1];
  if (typeof cb === 'function') {
    packet[packet.length - 1] = function() {
      const [err, data] = arguments;
      console.log(`end of request: ${id}`);
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      cb(err, data);
    };
  };
  next();
});
```